# My new Dell w/ Ubuntu Gnome won't show my external monitors (Sceptre)

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, monitor

My ubuntu Dell will not show my external monitors. I've downloaded and installed the driver for the StarTech Display link docking station I have, and the dock works for keyboard and mouse, but I cannot get Ubuntu to recognize the external monitors.

Nothing is there when I go to Settings and click on Display. I'm wondering if my Sceptre monitors don't work with Linux. I hope not. I cannot afford new ones.